# What exactly is current density?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

What exactly is the physical significance or meaning of Current density?

The formula $J=\frac{I}{A}$ is one thing but what does this represent, I am unable to visualize it or feel it.

We have already defined current as charge flowing through a cross section per unit time as current but now what does current density mean?

For example, while deriving the formula for magnetic field due to a infinite sheet, I came across the term **take current per unit area as $J$**, what information does this give me? I am really confused regarding current density and I don't have any intuitive feeling regarding it. How should I think about it? Please help.

Comment: Related : [Surface Current Density](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/640544/surface-current-density). From @Andrew Steane's answer : *"Current density" (without any other adjectives) means "charge passing a plane per unit time, per unit area of the plane". "Surface current density" means "amount of charge in a thin sheet of current passing a given place, per unit time, per unit length across the wide dimension of the sheet of current".*

Comment: @Frobenius Thanks, understanding it in terms on charge is a bit helpful  now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current is due to moving charges (electrons).

Imagine 9 electrons are moving into the paper (or screen)

[image]

Diagram A has a low current density, diagram B has a higher current density.

Comment: Are both currents same?

Answer (score 3):

Visualize a cross-section through an electric wire. The current density is the current divided by the cross-section's area. Increasing this area allows for a greater current, which is why a wire's resistance is inversely proportional to that area.

Comment: I approved your nice answer.